# VB.Net Linq to SQL GROUP BY without any aggregates

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying very hard to learn the concept of grouping and going in circles around the map, yet stopping at every village on that map.

I have imported a large data file from a CSV into a SQL Database using VB.NET This DATA represents sales there is a order id, Now the orderID can have multiple items in an order.

I am trying to do what should be so simple and that is to group the results based on order ID as the Key

I found what seems to be like a hundred examples of this very little really for VB.NET every time I do it, I either get errors, no data or 1 single column

I don't want aggregates and functions just a plain simple collection of data where I can apply to possibly  a templated 2nd datagrid within a first datagrid

I.E If anybody could steer me in the right direction I would be very happy right now. the main issue is i want all the data to show just sorted into groups.

its probably useless giving code as i have gone through so many methods and got no good result

but this one almost works as it it returns results yet it's not really hiding rows from the same order

```
Dim ordid = Request.QueryString("orderid")

        Dim conm As New csvtosqlDataContext

        Dim q = From p In conm.bidcomOrders Where p.OrderId = ordid Group p By p.OrderId, p.OrderTime, p.ItemTitle, p.BuyersFirstName, p.BuyersEmail, p.Status Into Group Select New With {.OrderId = Group, .OrderTime = OrderTime, .ItemTitle = ItemTitle, .BuyersFirstName = BuyersFirstName, .BuyersEmail = BuyersEmail, .Status = Status, Group}
        GridView1.DataSource = q
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the solution by watching videos and referencing methods in MSDN

My example was actually pretty simple I had tried so many ways using examples and they all resulted in error.  so if anyone else is pulling their hair out over the simple stuff and cant find the answer to a simple sorting of a single flat file here is how.

```
 Dim ordersbyorderid = From ord In conm.bidcomOrders
                     Order By ord.OrderId 
                     Group By Order_ID = ord.OrderId, Name = ord.BuyersFirstName, Surname = ord.BuyersLastName, email = ord.BuyersEmail, Status = ord.Status
    Into allorders = Group
                     Order By Order_ID
```

not sure why the guys at MS feel the need to complicate things and have to give columns new names but this is how its done

This code merely creates ordered lists you can use this result in a further expression using for each